# Preencher input's com dados do banco Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

Preciso que ao preencher o `input` CPF/CNPJ me traga o cep e cidade do cliente que está cadastrado no banco automaticamente após perder o foco do input CPF/CNPJ.

A consulta no banco não é um problema já está ok só gostaria de saber como retorno a informação dentro do `input` cep - cidade (haverá mais inputs estes são um exemplo).

Até agora só consegui retornar alguns dados de exemplo dentro de uma div.

**Formulario**

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="formulario">

    <legend><b>Dados do Destinatário da Entrega</b></legend>
    <label>Nome<br>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
    </label>

    <label>CPF/CNPJ<br>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" required>
    </label>

    <label>CEP<br>
        <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep">
    </label>

    <label>Cidade<br>
        <input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade">
    </label>

</form>

<div class="recebeDados"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formulario').submit(function() {
         var dados = $('#formulario').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'precontroller/precontroller_valida_form.php',
            data: dados,
            success :  function(data){
                $('.recebeDados').html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

**precontroller_valida_form.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

    //Consulta no banco

    echo $_POST['nome'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Vc teria que retornar um JSON `{"cep" : "cep do cara", "cidade" : "cidade do cara"}` e em seguida mandar esses valores para os respectivos inputs. No Caso teria que fazer um AJAX pra isso dentro de um callback de um evento blur no campo do CPF/CNPJ.

Comment: Entendi, consegue me dar um exemplo dentro desse meu contexto ? Não utilizo muito AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é a reposta do AJAX, para facilitar o uso da resposta, use o `json_encode` no PHP e no AJAX defina o tipo para JSON.

Exemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="formulario">

    <legend><b>Dados do Destinatário da Entrega</b></legend>
    <label>Nome<br>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome">
    </label>

    <label>CPF/CNPJ<br>
        <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" required>
    </label>

    <label>CEP<br>
        <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep">
    </label>

    <label>Cidade<br>
        <input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade">
    </label>

</form>

<div class="recebeDados"></div>

<script>

        $('#cpf').blur(function() {
            var dados = $('#formulario').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url  : 'precontroller/precontroller_valida_form.php',
                data: dados,
                success :  function(data){
                    $('#cidade').val(data.cidade);
                    $('.recebeDados').html(data.cidade);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

</script>
```

precontroller_valida_form.php

```
<?php

$dados = array();
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

    //Consulta no banco
    $dados['nome'] = $reposta_consulta['nome'];
    $dados['cidade'] = $reposta_consulta['cidade'];

    echo json_encode($dados);
}

?>
```

ou

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

    //Consulta no banco
    echo json_encode($reposta_consulta);
}

?>
```

Comment: Olá, testei e não retornou nada dentro do input nem na div.

Comment: verifica o retorno do ajax no devtools para ver se esta retornando o valor correto

Comment: Não está retornando nada pelo devtools, se eu der um var_dump($dados); retorna

Comment: dá echo no `json_encode`

Comment: Também retorna dando echo, agora foi era só o echo mesmo :/

Comment: mantem o echo e coloca um `console.log(data)` no no `success` do AJAX